How to use subquery into field on gorm query
I have a query like this:
select a.id, 
  (
    select max(b.last_update_login) 
    from login_history b 
    where b.user_id = a.id  
  ) last_update_login
from user a

How do I convert this into a Gorm query?

Did you check the doc?
https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#SubQuery

You can also execute as raw SQL. https://gorm.io/docs/sql_builder.html

Example：
Use Package:
"gorm.io/driver/mysql"
"gorm.io/gorm"
CodeExample:
type MailModel struct {
    Pid        uint64
    Createtime int64
}
var mailList []*MailModel
mysql.Table("lobbyplayer a").
    Select("a.pid, MAX(b.createtime) as createtime").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN mails b ON b.pid = a.pid").
    Group("a.pid").
    Find(&mailList)


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
